# Plivo Inbound Sip trunk - issue with destination number

Tags: sip, plivo

I'm trying to forward calls from few Plivo numbers to my Asterisk server. In Plivo documentation specified, that i have to build Inbound trunk application and return to plivo XML code below:

```
<Response>
<Dial callerId="18004321321">
    <User>sip:yoda12312312@phone.plivo.com</User>
</Dial>
</Response>
```

But the problem is that i need to add information about destination phone number (cause i have few of them), but can't find the way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
<Response>
    <Dial callerId="18004321321">
        <User>sip:yoda12312312@phone.plivo.com</User>
        <Number>180012345678</Number>
    </Dial>
 </Response>
```

Comment: In this case Plivo will connect both sip and specified number. My issue was resolved by adding custom SIP-headers.